# Jquery droppable added via mouseover event does not see OVER event

Tags: jquery, mouseover, droppable

Because I may have a 1000 (or more) DIVS that all can be dragged and dropped onto one another, I found that putting the jquery .droppable on all the DIVs when the page finishes loading takes way too long. So, I have tried to use the mouseover function to add the droppable only to those DIVs that the user actually tries to drop something on.

This works fine for the drop: but does not act as expected for the over:

Here is a snippet of the code

```
$('.nc').mouseover(function() { 
   $(this).droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',

      over: function( event, ui ) { // do this .. highlight the div being dropped on // },

      out: function(event, ui) { // do this .. unhighlight the div being dropped on // },

      drop: function( event, ui ) { // do this .. handle the drop even  // }

   });
});
```

When I drop onto any DIV with the .nc class, the drop actually works fine. However, the "over" does not work when I drag an item onto the DIV unless my mouse has gone over the DIV prior to trying to drag something on it.

Note, i know that I could use the hoverClass to highlight, but I need to provide some logic in the over event so that it only highlights under certain conditions.

I've been fighting this for a long time, so hope someone can help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the lines

```
  over: function( event, ui ) { // do this .. highlight the div being dropped on // },

  out: function(event, ui) { // do this .. unhighlight the div being dropped on // },

  drop: function( event, ui ) { // do this .. handle the drop even  // }
```

the ending "}" is commented out so it breaks the function

```
$('.nc').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',

      over: function( event, ui ) {  },

      out: function(event, ui) {  },

      drop: function( event, ui ) { }

   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my code has the }, at the end of each.  I simply forgot to include that in my pseudo-code.  thanks for trying.  My issue is still open.